# How to deal with scoping concerns within MVC controllers using entity framework and Ninject for dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

Essentially I have a set of controllers that will have business layer objects injected into them, these business layer objects will require data access layer objects that will primarily be using entity framework.

The area where me and my team are a little lost is how/when these injected database contexts will be created. Our main concern is that we do not want new contexts being created every time a request comes in since we do quite a bit of ajax requests. Here is some of our thoughts so far

1. **transient scope** 
   We came to the conclusion that this would lead to new contexts being created for every request to the controller even if the request was just an ajax request that does not require the entity context. Plus we would be required to dispose of the context.
2. **Parent scope**

     This is better than the first since ninject would handle disposing of the context. But it still has the issue of newing up a new instance for every request.
3. **singleton scope**
   Not practical due to memory concerns for large numbers of connections using   the same database context
4. **request scope** 
   We felt this would essentially lead to the exact behaivor as using transient scoping since MVC creates a new controller for each request

All of these are based on our assumption that MVC will be creating new controllers for each request (rather than keeping them around as the same user makes requests to the site) also that the entity framework objects being created would be a memory concern.

Are our assumptions correct? If so is there a way for us to keep a particular instance of the entity framework context or our controllers alive on a per user basis.

EDIT:

An example of something that we want to avoid is below. From what I understand the same client issuing multiple ajax call's to ScrollResults due to a user scrolling in the ui would result in a new controller and IContext being generated. The SomeAjaxMethod would also cause a new EF object to be created even though it will not use it. However if having a new EF object being newed up has a negligible effect on performance then we can live with that.

```
//Context would be our entity framework object that would be injected
public SomeController(IContext context )
{
    _ctx = context;
}
//Ajax method that loads more data whenever the user scrolls to far
public JsonResult ScrollResults(int group){
        this._ctx.stuff();
}
public JsonResult SomeAjaxMethod(int group){
      //Stuff that does not require the entity connection, but still causes 
      //a new controller and entity framework object to be created
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing EXACTLY how you have your AJAX interactions set up, it's difficult to answer specifically.

I'm sure that for some very specific circumstances you might need to stray away from Request Scope, but I have not yet found that reason myself in my day-to-day work.

Request scope maps itself very well to the flow of a web request. There is no issue creating new contexts for each request in any of the work I have done. Could you provide a scenario in your project where this would be undesirable? Or is it just the performance point of view which you are concerned about?

If you think about the life cycle of an Entity Framework DbContext, Request Scope is actually perfect for web projects. Let's pretend that you used the same context for both web User A and User B. If User A reads 10 news items, then edits 1 and saves it. What happens when User B comes along to look at products? The context already contains 10 news items (and the edited 1).

What business does User 2 have with News Items in the context which they are using? This is inefficient, so Request Scope solves this problem by issuing a new context for every request. You have automatic segregation between each web request.

Comment: Thanks for responding I edited my question with a trivial example. Based on what you already said I am beginning to feel that maybe we are just micro optimizing.

Comment: Ok I see what you are getting at. I doubt you would notice a difference in performance, but you could test it by splitting the action which is invoked by AJAX into a separate controller which has no injected attributes. Benchmark the two, and see if there is any merit in keeping it that way. I think you'll find that any performance gain is vastly outweighed by extra hassle. It will be fun finding out though, and I'll be interested in the result.